# How can i keep running my method when the input is incorrect

Tags: java, validation, input, java.util.scanner

Hello everyone i just started programming with java but i have kinda a problem question i am making a game where the user needs to put in a a number between 1 and 9 if the user puts a number under 1 or above 9 it gives an error and the user needs to put in a number again but when the user puts in a invalid number the program gives an error and stops working how can i fix this?

My code

```
 public void game()
{

    Scanner inputnumber = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please select a number (1-9): ");
    int number = inputnumber.nextInt();
   if (number <1 || number > 9)
   {
       System.out.println("Please select a number: " + number);
       System.out.println("This value is out of range. Please enter a value between 1 and 9.");

       while (number <1 || number > 9)
       {
           return;
       }
   }
   else{
       System.out.println("That is a valid entry!");
   }
}
```

}

Comment: what error? what does "stops working" mean? What do *you* expect `while (number <1 || number > 9) { return; }` to do?

Comment: if it is lower then 1 or higher then 9 the user gets a error/warning and needs to input a number again i am new to java

Comment: @snm when does it have to stop the program?

Comment: when the numbers are between 1 and 9 yes if it is  not then it needs to repeat the quesion

Answer (score 0):

This would also serve the purpose.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner inputnumber = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;
    do{
      System.out.println("Please select a number (1-9): ");
      n = inputnumber.nextInt();
    } while ( n >= 1 && n <= 9);
  }
}
```

you can use a do while loop for this.
**todo** Handle exceptions to support your use case.

Comment: What happens if you enter 1 or 9? Note they are valid as well.

Comment: Yep. The print statement mislead me. I thought the number has to be between 1 and 9.

Answer (score -1):

One thing which you can try is to use `try catch` block.

For example :

```
public class ab {
    int inputNumber;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        takeInput();    
    }
    public static void takeInput()
    {
        Scanner inputnumber = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please select a number (1-9): ");
        try {
                int number = inputnumber.nextInt();
                if (number >=1 && number <=9) {
                    System.out.println("Valid Number");
                }
                else
                {
                    takeInput();
                }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("Invalid number");
            takeInput();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why, what exception are you trying to catch? And your code does not solve the actual problem at hand.

Comment: Added the changes. Moreover to answer your question as to what exception it is accepting, the user is `nextInt` so that means it needs integer. Any exception other than that is being watched.